# How Do I Force A Flyout To Load / Instantiate in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app I have a Flyout with a ComboBox in it. When the user changes the selected item, the ComboBox.SelectionChanged event fires.

The problem is when my app tries to change the index from the code behind. In this scenario, the app navigates to the page with a parameter that says the ComboBox should have index #2 selected.

```
Frame.Navigate( typeof(ExamplePage) , 2)  // Parameter = 2
```

Since the page has just been navigated to, the Flyout has not been loaded / instantiated yet. It only instantiates when the Flyout.ShowAt() method is called.

But once I click the button that instantiates the Flyout and brings it into view, the SelectionChanged event on the ComboBox actually fires and I get the expected behavior.

How do I force a Flyout to load / instantiate when the page is navigated to without calling the ShowAt() method? I don't want the load strategy of the Flyout to be "Lazy"; it needs to load immediately.

Comment: It's impossible to load/instantiate the Flyout without calling the ShowAt() method. Please explain why you want this kind of behavior.

Comment: I realize now that I was mixing up MVC. I was relying on the ComboBox to tell me the selected index, but since it was not loaded, it was returning -1. To remedy this, I am binding the SelectedIndex to a separate field in code behind. It works now.

Comment: @XavierXie a good scenario for this would be if the flyout contains a TreeView, we would like to forcibly select the correct node in the tree.